# Can my employer see what I'm doing from my personal computer?

Tags: vpn, remote-desktop

I hated switching up my keyboard, mouse, and monitor every time I had to switch to my work laptop. Basically, my setup now is from my personal computer, I use windows RDP and remote into my work laptop, then from my work laptop, I connect to the company's vpn. I was wondering if my employer can see what I'm doing on my personal computer like this? Thanks.

Comment: While connected or not connected to your employer’s VPN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No they can't see what you are doing on your personal PC..  They  may be able to see you are connecting in to the work machine from home though - depending on how its set up.

If your PC and the company laptop are both on the same LAN this is likely Ok'ish as long as you are using RDP and not something like Teamviewer which goes via the Internet.  That said it is still significantly less secure then connecting directly from the PC. If it were my network and you did this behind my back I'd be upset with you.

If your company is knowledgeable enough to deploy VPN infrastructure they will have someone you should be getting to sign off on what you are doing.  They may prefer to buy you a docking station, monitor and keyboard then have you circumvent their security model (or they may be entirely OK woth what you are doing depending in your level of access and their security model)

Comment: A KVM switch might also be a solution.

Comment: +1 .. to elaborate, `No they can't see what you are doing on your personal PC` .. *sort of* depending on how its setup like davidgo says.. BUT, if the VPN is routing ALL traffic through the VPN (common), then yes, they can see every website you hit and any unencrypted traffic.  It depends on the configuration of the [routing table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routing_table) and [DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) as to what traffic goes to what server.  As a rule, pretend like they can see EVERYTHING done while connected unless you understand ROUTE and DNS.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Thank you for this.  Its probably worth noting that as the VPN runs from the work laptop, only non-lan traffic through the laptop will go via the VPN.